# How do I create multiple nodes on the same page?

Tags: 7, forms

Im on d7. I am trying to create node submission process where I can create multiple nodes on the same submit page and have them all reference a single separate node on the site. any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create multiple nodes by creating node objects and using node_save() function to save the node.

```
      $node = new stdClass();
      $node->nid = NULL;
      $node->nid = NULL;
      $node->is_new=TRUE;
      $node->type = "CONTENT_TYPE_NAME";

      node_object_prepare($node);

      $node->created = strtotime("now");
      $node->changed = strtotime("now");

      $node->uid = 1;
      $node->promote = 1;
      $node->format = 1;
      $node->language = 'en';
      $node->title = '"TITLE" ';

      $node->field_DATA['und'][0]['value']= "VALUE";
      $node->field_DATA['und'][0]['value']= "VALUE";

     // Prepare node for saving
      node_save($node);
```

you can create multiple objects like this on submit handler and save it. Each node will be assigned with new node id.

I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe field collection module is not a bad alternative, but it's not as perfect as node.