# How do I show multiple nodes on the same page without writing code?

Tags: 7

Let's say on my "contact" page, I want to use a google map (module), contact form (webform module), show our address (node using Address field), and list some social icons. Let's say stacked on top of each other in the "content" region.

What is the easiest way to do that?

Note: this similar question involves code, I want to avoid that:

[How do I create multiple nodes on the same page?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/40232/how-do-i-create-multiple-nodes-on-the-same-page)

Answer (score 2):

I came to a similar situation of your question before. I need a page, divided to two parts. On left shows company info such as Google map, company address, phone number etc. On the right side, shows a "Webform-ed" Contact Us form. The single page is actually a Panel node of a combination of two other nodes.

My solution is use Panel modules.

Enable modules:

[image]

Create a Panel Node, pick a layout of the Panel node. 
[image]

[image]

Add content to each place.
[image]

Select existing node you created. (e.g Company info node  & Contact us node)
[image]

Answer (score 1):

use the [display suite](http://www.drupal.org/project/ds) module and make blocks for each item. put the blocks into a custom view mode. you could also use like either [entity_view_modes](http://drupal.org/project/entity_view_mode) or [view_mode_page](http://drupal.org/project/view_mode_page) to create the custom 'view modes' for your content.

In general, its neat to be able to do all this with an administrative UI (Views UI, DS interface, Field UI view modes); but all of these modules can have a steep learning curve by themselves -- let alone working together. Also, these are not small modules depending on your host environment.

Doing a custom page with `hook_page_build` or `hook_page_alter` and making blocks in code or with the views_ui can be much leaner.

To each his own.

Comment: so, if I *did* want to do it in code, I'd make my own module, called say "neils-contact-page" and use those hooks to set it up? thx

Comment: I love to use display suite with Entity Reference, especially when I need to limit the results of the nodes referenced. http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/44337/limit-results-of-the-entity-reference/48118#48118

Answer (score 1):

Use Entity Reference module at http://drupal.org/project/entityreference .

Create a new content type called "Contact Page" or whatever you want to call it. Add a field called "Embedded Nodes" of type Entity Reference with the autocomplete widget. In the field configuration, designate which nodes the field can reference in target bundles and set number of values to unlimited. After save, go to manage display and for the format of the "Embedded Nodes" field, choose "Rendered Entity". You can also choose which view mode to use - Full Content is fine. So now when you create a content type, you can reference other nodes to be displayed within the node. You can embed and re-order nodes at will without views.